# How to use redux thunk to redirect after success or error?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm a newbie to Promises and React. I'm using redux-thunk in my action creators to resolve promises and I'm calling the action creators from my component. How do I route to a different URL after successful or unsuccessful request completion? I'm attaching the code for a delete function action creator.

Should I set the state with a parameter (routeTo) when I dispatch it, on success?

Here's the delete function:

```
export function deletePost(id){
    var request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);

    return function(dispatch){
        request.then((response)=>{
            console.log("I deleted"+response.data.title);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("DELETE_ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function from an onclick function in my component.

```
deletePost(){
    this.props.deletePost(this.props.params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way I have found to do routing with redux is to consider the URI part of my state, and store it within redux.  There is an excellent library [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) that will do this for you.

Once you have react-router-redux setup, then you can just dispatch actions to change location, so your thunk would look like:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export function deletePost(id){
    var request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);

    return function(dispatch){
        request.then((response)=>{
            console.log("I deleted"+response.data.title);
            dispatch(push('/delete-success-uri'));
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("DELETE_ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(error));
            dispatch(push('/delete-fail-uri'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to create cases in reducers for this but it felt too hacky.